# Solr: Get a hierarchy facets from date

Tags: date, filter, solr, facet

I want to get facets from solar divided by Year and Month (with relative number of element). I tried this query but it doesn't work.

```
solr/knowledge_base/select?facet.field=creationDate
&facet.date=creationDate
&facet.date.start=NOW-10YEAR
&facet.date.end=NOW
&facet.date.gap=+1MONTH
&facet=on
&facet.mincount=1
&q=*:*
&wt=json
```

Comment: can you give an example of document structure?

Comment: @root545 i want a return like this:
2018/01 (jan)
2018/02 (feb)
and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your facet parameter names are wrong - the name is `facet.range`, not `facet.date`. You probably also want to do `NOW/MONTH` to get the start of the month for your first bucket as well, instead of having your buckets move through the month as time passes.

So for your actual range parameters:

```
&facet.range=creationDate
&facet.range.start=NOW/MONTH-10YEAR
&facet.range.end=NOW
&facet.range.gap=+1MONTH
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. I replace '+1MONTH' with '%2B1MONTH'.
After that, i want response like this: 2018/2018-01, 2018/2018-02/ and so on... how can i do that?

Comment: Yes, the `+` vs `%2B` thing is for URL escaping. You do the reformatting in your view code or controller.